# Quickly press this key when a specific key is pressed. How prevent the trigger key to be pressed? (c++)

Tags: c++, keyboard, key, signals

I'm sorry if the title is unclear.. buuut I didn't know how to put things shorter :c
The (extract) code below is supposed to quickly press / send key 'A' if key 'U' is pressed / sent. But if I press 'U' it will first send 'U', then several 'A' right after. How can I make it such that key 'U' is not sent at all? I have tried different things but I couldn't get it to work... I think the problem lies within the if-condition :/

```
INPUT ip; // Structure for creating keyboard-events
ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD; // Create a generic keyboard-event
ip.ki.wScan = 0;       // Hardware-Scan-Code for the key
ip.ki.time = 0;        //
ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0; //

for (;;) {
    sleep_for(milliseconds(1)); // Sleep in each iteration so the CPU / RAM have a relaxed life
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x55)) {   // If key 'U' is pressed
        ip.ki.wVk = 0x41;                 // Press key 'A'
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;                //
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT)); //

        ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;    // Release key that was pressed
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));   //
    }
}
```

Comment: `sleep_for(milliseconds(1))` - red flag. There are *extremely few* valid uses of (any variation of) `sleep`. Usually it's a bug. Why do you think you need a `sleep` here? If you are just trying to reduce CPU use, a better option would be asynchronous APIs and callback functions.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I have tested it on my computer and saw that when I'm inside this infite loop without a sleep, this program takes like 20% of my CPU / RAM and making my computer very loud... But once I set a little sleep timer there, it's all good and costs are below 1% :)

Comment: But what you *should* be doing is *not* busy looping and putting the process to sleep. You *should* be using APIs that let the program sleep until something happens to wake it up. You are doing it wrong. You are polling while you should be sleeping, waiting for an asynchronous callback. Your sleep is adding latency for the case where work needs to be done and your loop is wasting time for when no work needs to be done. Worst of both worlds.

Comment: It may look like "if I apply this hammer things look good", but in reality, things are not good - they are terrible, and if you ever try to scale this hackish solution up to a *real* program, you'll feel the pain and it won't work properly.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Ohh now I see what you mean. But I'm kinda new to c++ and I made it this way with the for-loop because I didn't know about any other way of keeping this program 'alive' and execute it when I need it at some point (can you give me some more hints or maybe links of an example?). But even if I did all that, I don't think it would solve the problem I was originally asking for~

Comment: Read up on event loops.

Comment: To help with your research, Microsoft uses the term *Message Loop*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling GetAsyncKeyState() in a loop.  If detects if the key is pressed down.  It is calling the function multiple times during the time that key is pressed.  When you press a key it's typically for 5-25 milliseconds, so GetASyncKeyState() is detecting the key press multiple times.

GetASyncKeyState() returns a short integer, if the least significant bit is set, then the key was already detected in a previous call to GetASyncKeyState()

To fix your code, just check this bit using the bitwise operator AND

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x55) &1)
```

This is also useful when toggling booleans or features.